API Gateway OpenAPI - pass custom variables from API Gateway to REQUEST typed Lambda Authorizer
Context: I would like to know how I can pass a custom variable like roles: ["ROLE_ORDER_READ", "ROLE_ORDER_WRITE"] from API Gateway OpenAPI to my REQUEST typed Lambda Authorizer. I don't know if the custom variable needs to be stringified for AWS but it's OK i can stringify if I have to.
My current OpenAPI definition:
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/contacts/{id}/orders:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: arn:$${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:$${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambda_get_order_arn}/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
      security:
        - lambda_authorizer: []

What I "want to do" (but this won't work of course):
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/contacts/{id}/orders:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: arn:$${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:$${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambda_get_order_arn}/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
        # SEE HERE:
        customVariables:
            roles: ["ROLE_ORDER_READ", "ROLE_ORDER_WRITE"]
      security:
        - lambda_authorizer: []

Questions:

How can I achieve that with OpenAPI? Is there a specific x-amazon-apigateway-XXX to use?
Then how to access this custom roles variable from the event or context parameters of my Lambda Authorizer?

Notes:

I use Terraform with OpenAPI definition, I don't use CloudFormation
I would like to pass custom variables from the API Gateway to the Lambda Authorizer (not from Lambda Authorizer to business lambda)
Each routes defined in the OpenAPI will have its own roles passed to the Lambda Authorizer


You can try using mapping templates, to modify your request and add your custom variables
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/contacts/{id}/orders:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: arn:$${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:$${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambda_get_order_arn}/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: |
            # write your template here, adding your variables
      security:
        - lambda_authorizer: []

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestTemplates.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-mappings

Hi @Rachelle, I have already tried this, but the Lambda Authorizer seems to be executed BEFORE the x-amazon-apigateway-integration, and I need to access to these roles inside the Lambda Authorizer for comparing with the roles of the Authorization header
